# Display Board in a Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a simple tic-tac-toe game which is proving to be not so simple (at least to me, I'm a beginner). I'm having trouble writing the display_board function which should print something like this:

```
_|_|_
_|_|_
 | |
```

And add an X or an O when the player marks the board to a specific location. What I'm planning to do is put this all into a character string but it's kind of confusing especially with the new lines I want to add so the board comes out properly. Does a new line operator count as one or two characters in a string?
If you want to look at my code for the game, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int board[3][3] = {
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0}
                  };

int main (void)
{
    int const user1 = 1;
    int const user2 = 2;
    char move[];

    while (! all_locations_filled()) {
        printf("User-1, please enter your move:");
        scanf("%s", &move);

        if(valid_location(move)) {
            mark_location(user1, move);
            display_board();
        else if(won_the_game(user1) {
            printf("Congratulations User-1, You Won the Game!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Move");
        }
        }
        printf("User-2, please enter your move:");
        scanf("%s", &move);

        if(valid_location(move)) {
            mark_location(user2, move);
            display_board();
        else if(won_the_game(user2) {
            printf("Congratulations User-2, You Won the Game!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Move");
        }
        }
}

bool valid_location(char str[]) {
    if (str[] == "upperLeft" || str[] == "up" || str[] == "upperRight" || str[] == "left" || str[] == "center" || str[] == "right" || str[] == "lowerLeft" || str[] == "down" || str[] == "lowerRight") {
        return true;
    }
}

void mark_location(int userU, char str[]) {
    if (str[] == "upperLeft") {
        board[0][0] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "up") {
        board[0][1] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "upperRight") {
        board[0][2] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "left") {
        board[1][0] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "center") {
        board[1][1] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "right") {
        board[1][2] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "lowerLeft") {
        board[2][0] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "down") {
        board[2][1] = userU;
    else if (str[] == "lowerRight") {
        board [2][2] = userU;
    }
}
```

It's kind of messy, as I said I'm new too this. If you have any suggestions to clean it up, please feel free to give me a hand.

Comment: When this problem came up on CodeGolf.SE as [Noughts and Crosses (aka Tic-Tac-Toe)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1054/78), I used curses to control the display. That may be more support then you want, but it is still a pretty low level. (Look at the ungolfied version, BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors in your code. Here are some:

Use `strcmp` function to compare strings in C

`str[] == "upperLeft"`

is not a valid C expression.

Also this definition:

```
char move[];
```

is not a valid array definition, it misses the number of elements between the `[]`.

Moreover

```
scanf("%s", &move);
```

the `%s` conversion specification takes a pointer to char as an argument. The value of `&move` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to char. Call the function this way instead:

```
scanf("%s", move);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `strcmp` function to compare strings in C

```
str[] == "upperLeft"
```

is not a valid C expression.

Also this definition:

```
char move[];
```

is not a valid array definition, it misses the number of elements between the `[]`.

Moreover,

```
scanf("%s", &move);
```

the `%s` conversion specification takes a pointer to char as an argument. The value of `&move` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to char. Call the function this way instead:

```
scanf("%s", move);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the rows, and columns.
I don't want to write the answer for you, but something like...

```
function print_board()
    iterate over rows
       iterate over columns
           print board location
           if this is not the third spot, print a vertical bar character
       print a newline followed be a line of dashes followed by a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

A new line, `'\n'` or `"\n"`, counts as a single character, even though most terminals require two characters to output it. (In DOS/Windows this is achieved by the CRT converting `\n` to CRLF, while in Unix this is done by the TTY driver.)

Answer (score 0):

this is printf function for tic tac toe
void board()
{

```
printf("\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n");

printf("Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");


printf("     |     |     \n");
printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[1], square[2], square[3]);

printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
printf("     |     |     \n");

printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[4], square[5], square[6]);

printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
printf("     |     |     \n");

printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c \n", square[7], square[8], square[9]);

printf("     |     |     \n\n");
```

}

Comment: Try to provide some explanation, not just code. StackOverflow answers should aim to [teach a man to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)